# how to write linq query to make order by timestamp

Tags: c#, linq

[image]i want to keep the list of object in order by descending in timestamp. getting error saying - cannot convert list to string.

sample time from the model

> 12/09/2018 11:24:37 PM

```
 public ActionResult A()
 {
     var model = new AssetTrackersViewModel();
     model.AssetTrackers.Add(getAssetDetails_CH("e8", DateTime.Now.Date, DateTime.Now.Date));
     model = model.AssetTrackers.OrderByDescending(x => DateTime.Parse(x.time));//error 

     return View(model);
 }
```

class

```
 public class AssetTracker
 {
    public AssetTracker()
    {
        latitude = new List<string>();
        longitude = new List<string>();
        time = new List<string>();
    }
    public string deviceid { get; set; }
    public List<string> latitude { get; set; }
    public List<string> longitude { get; set; }
    public List<string> time { get; set; }               
}



public class AssetTrackersViewModel
{
    public AssetTrackersViewModel()
    {
        AssetTrackers = new List<AssetTracker>();
    }    
    public List<AssetTracker> AssetTrackers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: First, don't store date/time as a string. Use a `DateTime` object. Then your life will be much simpler.

Comment: `time` is a `List<string>` property of `AssetTracker` (and `DateTime` can't `Parse` a `List<string>`, which is why you're getting an error). How do you want to sort the `List<AssetTracker>` based on each item's `time` property? In other words, how do you want to compare one `time` list to another in order to determine the sort order?

Comment: Also you haven't mentioned your sort criteria. Your `AssetTrackers` is a list, and each item in it contains a list of `time` objects. So how to you want to sort the top list based on the inner list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are storing times as strings and in a list within the view model. Depending on what you want to accomplish:
I.e. Find the asset tracker with the latest time:

```
  model = model.AssetTrackers
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.time
      .Select(t=>DateTime.Parse(t)).OrderByDescending(t=>t).First())
      .FirstOrDefault();
```

The issue is that you're instructing Linq to apply DateTime.Parse against a `List<string>` rather than each individual string in the list.

I would recommend storing date times as DateTime rather than string, or at a minimum store them in ISO-8601 (YYYY-DD-MMTHH:mm:ss(Z)) since this can be compared and sorted.

Also, if you have a 1-to-many relationship between these asset trackers and times then I'd recommend mapping the relationship in the entities with the DateTimes. If the Database is storing DateTime, avoid casting to string, even if you want to format the dates in the view models. Let the view models expose a formatted date as a property but allow code to use DateTime since you can sort and compare on that accurately without the extra cost of DateTime.Parse.

Comment: getting error -operator . cannot applied to type void

Comment: Corrected the linq expression... That should have been `.Select()` rather than `.ForEach()`... Also the `.OrderByDescending()` needed an expression.

Answer (score 0):

`time` is a `List<string>` property of `AssetTracker` (and `DateTime` can't `Parse` a `List<string>`, which is why you're getting an error). How do you want to sort the `List<AssetTracker>` based on each item's time property? In other words, how do you want to compare one time list to another in order to determine the sort order?

Since you're comparing objects on a property that is a `List<string>`, you need some way to determine a baseline for what that property value is. Two ways to do this come to mind: `Min` and `Max`:

1. Take the maximum time from the list for each object and use that as a comparison:

   `model.AssetTrackers = model.AssetTrackers
       .OrderByDescending(x => x.time.Max(t => DateTime.Parse(t))).ToList();`
2. Take the minimum time from the list for each object and use that as a comparison:

   `model.AssetTrackers = model.AssetTrackers
       .OrderByDescending(x => x.time.Min(t => DateTime.Parse(t))).ToList();`

A third option, I suppose, would be to take the Average, which would be a little different since it requires a number type, not a date. But luckily we can use something the `Ticks` property for comparison:

3. Take the minimum time from the list for each object and use that as a comparison:

   `model.AssetTrackers = model.AssetTrackers
       .OrderByDescending(x => x.time.Average(t => DateTime.Parse(t).Ticks)).ToList();`

In any case, life would be much simpler if you stored the property as a (preferably UTC) `DateTime` object instead of a string. If the input is a string somewhere along the line, it's best to get any parsing errors out of the way up front, rather than when we're trying to process the data later.

Answer (score 0):

First, and I cannot stress this enough, it's not a good idea to store dates as strings. Just use DateTimes directly.

Your `AssetTracker` objects have a property named `time`.
This property is a list of strings. `DateTime.Parse` can not parse a list - it can parse a string. That's why you get your error message.

It's not completely clear from your question what you want to do.

Do you want to order the list of `AssetTracker` by the highest timestamp they have?

```
var trackersByHighestTimeDesc = 
   model.AssetTrackers
   .OrderByDescending(x => x.time.Select(DateTime.Parse).Max());
```

Do you want to order each list of timestamps, but keep the order of the asset trackers unchanged?

```
foreach(var at in model.AssetTrackers) {
    at.time = at.time.OrderByDescending(DateTime.Parse);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What do you want to sort? Because you are sorting AssetTrackers by List time or do you want to sort the List of time?

If you want to sort AssetTrackers look vor Min, Max, Avg on time.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer